# Problems with interruptions pic18f4550

Tags: c, embedded, microcontroller, pic

I am having troubles with the interruptions on the pic18f4550, with the MPLAB 8.89 and c18 compiler.

The point is, the interruption doesnt get in if the pin change is status. I can see the status change, but it just doesnt change. But, if write the interruption as one it goes and enter the routine.

Here is my code, any idea?

```
////// Autonomated Velocity Transmssion for a Bicycle of 9 gears/////

#include <p18f4550.h>

//////////////////////////////////////////// Variables /////////////////////////////////////////////////
unsigned int sensors=0;              // Counter of the sensor in the star
unsigned int sensorw=0;              // Counter of the sensor in the wheel
unsigned int rpms=0;                 // Rpms of the star
unsigned int rpmw=0;                 // Rpms of the wheel 
unsigned int velw;  

//////////////////////////////////////////// Interruption functions //////////////////////////////////////////////////
void Llanta (void);                  //Wheel 
void Estrella (void);                //Star 


/////////////////////////////////////// High Priority Interruptions /////////////////////////////////////////////////

#pragma code high_vector=0x08 
void high_interrupt (void) 
{   
     _asm nop _endasm 
}

//////////////////////////////////////////// Low Priority Interruptions //////////////////////////////////////////////////

#pragma code low_vector=0x18
void low_interrupt (void)
{
    if(INTCON3bits.INT1IF==1){      //interruption for INT1 on rising edge
         _asm goto Llanta _endasm   //Wheel
    } 

    if(INTCONbits.RBIF==1) {        //Interruption for change on RB port change
        _asm goto Estrella _endasm  //Star
    } 

}


#pragma code                
#pragma interruptlow Llanta 
void Llanta (void)              //Counts when the hall sensor of the wheel is activated
{    
    INTCON3bits.INT1IF=0;           //Turn off flag
    sensorw++;                    //add 
}


#pragma interruptlow Estrella           //Counts when the hall sensor of the star is activated
void Estrella (void) 
{   
    INTCONbits.RBIF=0;                  //Turn off flag 
    if(PORTBbits.RB4 == 1){       
        sensors++;                      //Add
    }   
}

////////////////////////////////////////////// Main program /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
void main (void) 
{ 
    unsigned int temp16;    
    OSCCON=0b01100000;          //Oscillator 4 MHz

    //Pins Configuration
    TRISBbits.RB1=1;            //input sensor wheel
    TRISBbits.RB4=1;            //input sensor star
    TRISB=0xFF;                 //All as inputs 

    T1CON=0b01000001;           // Oscillator 4 MHz, timer 1        
    ///////////////////////// Priorities //////////////////////////////// 

    RCONbits.IPEN=1;            //Enable priority levels 
    INTCON=0b11001000;          //Enable high, low interrupts and RB port change interrupt 
    INTCON2=0b01110000;         //Pull up disabled, interrupt on rising edge, and low priority on rb change
    INTCON3=0b00011000;         //low priority interruption, and enables external interruptions. 
    ADCON1=0x0F;                //digital input
    do{ 
        INTCON3bits.INT1IF=1;   // This was made to make a test. i put this as one, the interruption works and it goes where it should go. 
    }
    while(1); 
}
```

Comment: Please indent your code properly. This is unreadable, so I can't be bothered to read it. If you indent with the tab key, you should have your code editor set to inject spaces when you press tab.

Comment: Sorry about the indent, i just change the code to make it simple for the purpose of the interruption.

Comment: `INTCON3=0b00011000;  ` both `INT1IE` and `INT2IE` are set which means that `INT2` External Interrupt is enabled. But the corresponding flag is not handled is the interrupt function. Could `INTCON3=0b00001000;` solve the problem ?

Answer (score 1):

Check some of the following thoughts

1. check your configuration bits, more specifically your `CONFIG3H:
   CONFIGURATION REGISTER 3` and the `PBADEN` bit

   ```
   PBADEN: PORTB A/D Enable bit

   1 = PORTB<4:0> pins are configured as analog input channels on Reset 
   0 = PORTB<4:0> pins are configured as digital I/O on Reset
       If set to analog it won't register your pin status changes.
   ```
2. Make sure other PortB pins are not floating, ground them or turn
       them into outputs. Manual states

   ```
   RBIF: RB Port Change Interrupt Flag bit(1) 
   1 = At least one of the RB7:RB4 pins changed state (must be cleared in software) 
   0 = None of the RB7:RB4 pins have changed state

   Note 1: A mismatch condition will continue to set this bit.
   Reading PORTB, and then waiting one additional instruction cycle, 
   will end the mismatch condition and allow the bit to be cleared.
   ```
3. I would also clear the interrupt flag bit as the last instruction before exiting the interrupt not as first
4. Manual also states that

   "The interrupt-on-change feature is
       recommended for wake-up on key depression operation and operations
       where PORTB is only used for the interrupt-on-change feature.
       Polling of PORTB is not recommended while using the
       interrupt-on-change feature."

You are polling/reading the port inside your interrupt